# Seaborn does not show the bar graphics and others

Tags: python, seaborn

I am learning Data Science and I am trying to figure out why I see this difference.
What I get:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
diamonds = sns.load_dataset('diamonds')
df= diamonds.copy()
cut_categoriler= ["fair","good","very good","premium","ideal"]
df.cut= df.cut.astype(CategoricalDtype(categories = cut_categoriler, ordered= True))
df.head().T

sns.catplot(x= "cut" ,y= "price",data =df);
plt.show()
```

[image]

what I want:

[image]

Comment: I checked the DataFrame, the "cut" column if full of null values. That is why you are not getting a plot.

Comment: `carat  cut color clarity  depth  table  price     x     y     z`
`0   0.23  NaN     E     SI2   61.5   55.0    326  3.95  3.98  2.43`
`1   0.21  NaN     E     SI1   59.8   61.0    326  3.89  3.84  2.31`
`2   0.23  NaN     E     VS1   56.9   65.0    327  4.05  4.07  2.31`
`3   0.29  NaN     I     VS2   62.4   58.0    334  4.20  4.23  2.63`
`4   0.31  NaN     J     SI2   63.3   58.0    335  4.34  4.35  2.75`

Comment: "cut_categoriler= ["Fair","Good","Very Good","Premium","Ideal"]" I have changed only the caps of the first letters. then it shows the plot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do the cut operation that you are doing. The plot is pretty straightforward.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
diamonds = sns.load_dataset('diamonds')
df= diamonds.copy()
df.head()

sns.catplot(x= "cut" ,y= "price",data = df);
plt.show()
```

[image]